# How to model engagement score over time

Tags: model

I am trying to model an individual's 'engagement' with a document over time.

**Example:** A user receives a document at time t, they then download it at t+1. They could then come back to the same document and download it again (t+2). This second download action is seen as an indication of increased engagement and therefore the weight of this action should be more than the weight of the first.

- I'm look at downloads over a 28 day period.
- The total score for the user against a document should be the sum of all these download actions at certain times.
- I want the score for a user's engagement for a particular document to be on the scale from 0-1.

Any ideas for how to model this?

Answer (score 0):

Could happen that you have just a single variable model, where `numberOfdownloads` is the main variable. You would have to definite what is an `Engaged` reader, say someone who downloaded more than 40 times in 28 days period (you should check what the data says to choose the number that defines `Engaged`), for all others below this value, you can call them `notEngaged`, then changing them into 1 and 0 respectively, you can build a simple one variable logistic model that will give you a value between 0 and 1.